# Unable to download with playwright headless true from url link

Tags: javascript, automation, chromium, playwright, headless

I'm new to Playwright world, and my first question on stackoverflow

I'm trying to download a backup file from 'Aliphia' account. But with headless: true it doesn't download anything.
I tried multiple ways and nothing works

This is my code

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright-extra')
const stealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')();

chromium.use(stealth)

chromium.launch({ headless: true, acceptDownloads: true}).then(async browser =>{
      const context = await browser.newContext({
        acceptDownloads: true
      });
      const page = await context.newPage({ 
        acceptDownloads: true
      });
      await page.goto("https://aliphia.com/v1/app/");
      const frame = page.frame('aliapp');
      console.log('iFrame detected');
      const emailField = await frame.locator('#email');
      await emailField.waitFor();
      await emailField.fill(user.email);
      await frame.fill('#password',user.password);
      await frame.locator('[type="submit"]').click();
      console.log('log in btn clicked');
      await frame.waitForSelector('[class="sidebar"]').then(async()=>{
        console.log('success log in');
           const [download] = await Promise.all([
            page.waitForEvent('download'),
            await page.goto('https://aliphia.com/v1/settings/generate_backupfile')
           ]);
      

    });
```

it gives me err

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: page.goto: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://aliphia.com/v1/settings/generate_backupfile
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "https://aliphia.com/v1/settings/generate_backupfile", waiting until "networkidle"

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: page.waitForEvent: Timeout 30000ms exceeded while waiting for event "download"
```

I tried this

```
const client = await browser.pageTarget(page).createCDPSession();
await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
behavior: "allow",
downloadPath: "C:/in"
});
```

It doesn't download the required file nor detect it

Answer (score 0):

Dealt with this problem as well when trying to get playwright to simply download a file that I already have the url for.  Or do not have a page that I can start on to initiate a click, and therefore need to call goto straight on the download url.

I was able to get around it by surrounding the goto call with a try catch.  Try the following (slightly reorganized, to match my working code):

```
let promise = page.waitForEvent('download')
try {
   await page.goto('https://aliphia.com/v1/settings/generate_backupfile', { waitUntil: "networkidle" } )
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
}
let download = await promise
```

The key bit here is that the error you're seeing is a catchable.  I'm used to catchable thing being called exceptions, so that threw me off.  But it works for me.

I'm not sure if the goto option `{ waitUntil: "networkidle" }` is necessary, but somewhere in the morass of documentation that I've read, I picked it up and I like it.

H/T to yuri-s and this PR for the java code that I found while working on this: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-java/pull/558/files

Comment: pointless if your download is the result of a post call that a) requires a billion ephemeral request headers and b) a specific post body payload.